# OracleCallableStatement registerOutParameter doesn't like named binding

Tags: java, jdbc

this code gives "Incorrectly set or registered parameter" SQLException. Can anyone help please?

```
OracleConnection conn = getAppConnection();
String q = "BEGIN INSERT INTO tb (id) values (claim_seq.nextval) returning id into :newId; end;" ;
CallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(q);
cs.registerOutParameter("newId", OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cs.execute();
int newId = cs.getInt("newId");
```

Comment: `newId` isn't an OUT parameter, which IIRC requires you to use a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC does not support named binding, so it stops here.

Either live with indexed placeholders `?` or add an extra abstraction layer on top of JDBC which supports named parameters, e.g. [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) and/or [JPA](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html).

---

#### See also:

- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)
- [Hibernate manual, chapter 10.4.1.4 - Bind Parameters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing-parameters)

Comment: [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) has named binding, at list from SE 5. But if the procedure returns Oracle cursor, [OracleCallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) is needed, which seems to have only numbered binding. And cause of  "Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!" SQL Exception that spoils all the convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The following is just for documentation purposes but not really usable, since you **must** set the named parameters in the order they are specified in your sql String. So it works but is very error-prone. Here goes:

I got the same error for a similar constellation using oracle jdbc drivers version 10, but it worked for me after upgrading jdbc drivers to version 11. Version 12.x also works.
My code looks something like this:

```
int nextIdent;
String sql = "call pkg.do_insert(:NEXT_IDENT, :SOME_COL, ...)";
try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
    stmt.registerOutParameter("NEXT_IDENT", Types.INTEGER);
    stmt.setString("SOME_COL", "abc");
    ...
    stmt.execute();
    nextIdent = stmt.getInt("NEXT_IDENT");
}
```